# SQL DW Internal table data load taking long time

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I am facing issues in loading data between SQL DW Internal tables and I am trying to load just 50 records, thats there in my source - but the "Insert" statement is taking very long time and not executing succesfully [ It keeps running for more than 60 minutes ]

Few stats regarding this
•   Source table (say S1) has 50 records, 105 columns , Columnar Store, Round robin Distribution  on DWU 100 [ DDL of this table given below ]
•   Target table (say T1) has been created with same 105 columns, Columnar Store, Round robin Distribution  on DWU 100
•   Select top 5 * from S1 works 
•   Select * from S1 works
•   Insert into T1 as select * from S1 is running for long time with no response [ more than 60 minutes ]
•   Insert into T1 as select top 5 * from S1 , worked once and not working after that 
•   Insert into T1 as select top 5 all_columns_listed from S1 , works always and executes in < 1 minute
•   Insert into T1 as select top 30 all_columns_listed from S1 , works always and executes in < 1 minute
•   Insert into T1 as select top 50 all_columns_listed from S1 , is running for more than 25 minutes

I am unable to understand, what might be happening in the background  - when insert into T1 as select * from S1 is running;

Is something going wrong with DMS ? or is this because we have 105 columns ?

All above operations was tried by scaling up to DWU 200 - but still no luck.

All above operations was tried on altogether different database, still no luck.

Is there any thing else that can be checked on what is happening ? How to handle this ?

Also I have tried running below statement to see- if there are any other queries running actively - which might make my insert statement suspended or wait.. but I could see- only my query was actively running on the DB..
 select * from "sys"."dm_pdw_exec_requests" where status='Running' order by submit_time desc

S1 DDL is given below
CREATE  TABLE       S1
(
        col1    [uniqueidentifier]  NOT NULL,
        col2    nvarchar    NULL,
        col3    [uniqueidentifier]  NULL,
        col4    nvarchar NULL,
        col5    nvarchar    NULL,
        col6    [decimal](26,   6)  NULL,
        col7    [decimal](26,   6)  NULL,
        col8    [decimal](26,   6)  NULL,
        col9    [decimal](26,   6)  NULL,
        col10   [decimal](27,   6)  NULL,
        col11   [decimal](27,   6)  NULL,
        col12   [decimal](26,   6)  NULL,
        col13   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col14   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col15   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col16   nvarchar    NULL,
        col17   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col18   [smallint]  NULL,
        col19   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col20   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col21   [decimal](26,   6)  NULL,
        col22   [decimal](26,   6)  NULL,
        col23   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col24   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col25   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col26   [int]   NULL,
        col27   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col28   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col29   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col30   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col31   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col32   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col33   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col34   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col35   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col36   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col37   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col38   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col39   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col40   [int]   NULL,
        col41   nvarchar NULL,
        col42   [smallint]  NULL,
        col43   [smallint]  NULL,
        col44   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col45   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col46   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col47   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col48   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col49   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col50   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col51   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col52   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col53   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col54   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col55   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col56   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col57   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col58   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col59   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col60   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col61   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col62   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col63   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col64   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col65   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col66   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col67   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col68   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col69   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col70   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col71   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col72   nvarchar    NULL,
        col73   nvarchar    NULL,
        col74   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col75   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col76   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col77   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col78   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col79   nvarchar    NULL,
        col80   nvarchar    NULL,
        col81   nvarchar    NULL,
        col82   nvarchar    NULL,
        col83   nvarchar    NULL,
        col84   nvarchar    NULL,
        col85   nvarchar    NULL,
        col86   nvarchar    NULL,
        col87   nvarchar    NULL,
        col88   nvarchar    NULL,
        col89   [bit]   NULL,
        col90   nvarchar    NULL,
        col91   nvarchar    NULL,
        col92   datetimeoffset NULL,
        col93   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col94   nvarchar    NULL,
        col95   nvarchar    NULL,
        col96   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col97   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col98   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col99   [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col100  [decimal](25,   6)  NULL,
        col101  datetimeoffset NULL,
        col102  nvarchar    NULL,
        col103  nvarchar    NULL,
        col104  nvarchar    NULL,
        col105  nvarchar    NULL,
        col106  nvarchar    NULL,
        col107  datetimeoffset NULL,
        col108  datetimeoffset NULL,
        col109  varchar   NULL
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
    HEAP
)

Answer (score 1):

If you're loading data into an empty table you should consider using `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` (CTAS) rather than `INSERT INTO ...` to allow DW to fully parallelize the operation across nodes.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas/ explains CTAS, and https://saldeloera.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/pdw-performance-tip-ctas-vs-insert-select/ has a fuller comparison.

Comment: nope.. Its not a empty table.. Target table(T1) will be our main table, where we would be doing incremental data from Source table(S1). 
For testing purpose - I tried going with CTAS as 
create table  T2
WITH (HEAP, DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN) 
 as select   *
   FROM S1 and the statement is running for more than 15 minutes [ again, S1 has only 50 records ] and also noticed this is the only active query running on 200 DWU database server.

Comment: Hey Aravind. Do you know what the resource class you're using? If you're using the default admin account, then you are using the smallest resource class. If these columns are large enough, you might be memory constrained. If it is the case you're using a small resource class, try making a larger resource class user and trying again. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-develop-concurrency/#change-a-user-resource-class-example

Comment: Hi , I tried with 100DWU - smallrc, largerc and xlargerc - no luck 
also tried with 200DWU - smallrc,  largerc , xlargerc - no luck 

The S1 (source has) 50 records, 105 columns

Comment: Table stats
two_part_name [S1]
table_row_count 50
table_reserved_space_GB 0.004752
table_data_space_GB 0.001152
table_index_space_GB 0
table_unused_space_GB 0.0036

Comment: What are your permissions on this server?  Could it be something very intensive is running but you can't see it due to your permissions?  Consider raising a support ticket via the portal "New support request" option.

Comment: I tried running these statements with admin credentials too, but still the same problem. I have tried running these statements for the last 2 days - during different time [ just to make sure, any backup or system activities is not conflicting with the data loads that I am running]

Comment: If you can post the actual code you are running, then we might be able to spot something.  Otherwise, let us know how you get on with your support ticket.

Comment: S1 [source table] DDL is given above. S1 and T1 [Target table] DDLs are the same

insert into T1 select * from S1 is my SQL - thats running for long time [ S1 has 50 records ]

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this locally.  I set up your tables as described and was able to insert 50 records from one table to an empty one in my warehouse in 2 seconds at 400 DWU.  Please post the exact INSERT statement you are running.  Just some observations about your table, `nvarchar` without any length defaults to a length of 1.  As already suggested, consider raising a support ticket via the Azure portal.  This option is available from within the warehouse section.

Comment: insert into T1 select * from S1 

is my Insert statement that I am running.

I am working with Microsoft team now, looks like its a DMS issue. [ DMS is getting hung ]

Comment: It would be great if you could update the post when you have an answer from MS as it will help others with the same issue.  Even post it as an answer and mark it answered yourself if you like : )

Comment: I heard its a defect that Microsoft is working on fixing. In our case the row size is >32KB and hence data movement service was unable to move the data between the distributions and hence it was hung..

Comment: Interesting I could not reproduce this with my query.  Why do you think that is?